# Loading PNG image from file to memory buffer using libharu

Tags: c++, libharu

I want to load PNG image from file to buffer and then to `HPDF_Image`, but I can't get image from buffer using `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromMem`, as it returns `HPDF_INVALID_PNG_IMAGE`.

```cpp
    // Getting size
    std::ifstream t("3CM//A_3cm2.png");
    t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = t.tellg();

    // Filling buffer
    std::string buffer(size, ' ');
    t.seekg(0);
    t.read(&buffer[0], size);

    // Loading Image from buffer
    HPDF_Image image = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromMem(pdf, (HPDF_BYTE*) buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
```

Comment: Rather than `string`, you may want buffer to be a `vector<uint8_t>` or simply an array of `uint8_t` to avoid possible character set and encoding issues. Otherwise, the use and syntax of what you are doing looks OK.

Comment: Is the buffer correct? Is the PNG itself correct? My first guess would be reading binary data as windows text (which changes \n characters). Also check return values on the IO calls.

Comment: You are not checking if your file operations succeed. Is the file (`"3CM//A_3cm2.png"`) even opened correctly? Why the double directory separator in the name btw?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to load the image in de memory first ?
This code code work fine

```
HPDF_Doc   Pdf     = HPDF_New                  ( error_handler , NULL   ) ;
HPDF_Page  Page    = HPDF_AddPage              ( Pdf                    ) ;

HPDF_Image MyImage = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile ( Pdf ,"3CM//A_3cm2.png" ) ; 
HPDF_REAL  Width   = HPDF_Image_GetWidth       ( MyImage                ) ;
HPDF_REAL  Height  = HPDF_Image_GetHeight      ( MyImage                ) ;

HPDF_Page_DrawImage ( Page , MyImage , x , y , Width , Height ) ;
```

...